# USB TV tuner hardware or software issue

Tags: windows-7, tv

I am trying to run Intex USB Tv Tuner device on Windows 7.

I had installed its driver and application (honestech TVR 3.0). From the control panel, I can see that the driver is installed successfully and device is being detected.
The device has 3 ports.

1. to connect device with PC/Laptop (USB port)
2. to connect cable wire
3. for audio output as I guess.

But I don't know if any additional configuration is required. As per my knowledge, after connecting the device I just need to start honestech or Windows media player. But they are not detecting the device.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well my problesm has been resolved, when i installed it on Windows XP. In windows 7 it was installing default drivers coming with OS itself. I installed latest version of TV application. But it dint work.
The same i tried on my another machine having windows XP. And it worked on first attempt only. So there is no issue with hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the software? When I tried one of those, it included a dedicated tuner/player module that was independent of the players. And it allowed recording, too.

[image]

If the device uses a simulated serial port, you may need to adjust the port numbers.

Comment: i already mentioned in the question that i am using honestech TVR 3.0. Suggest if if some good in your knowledge